# What does the "get" do in "var simpleDescription: String {get}"?

Tags: swift

I see this example in Apple Swift [Tour](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html) page.

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}
```

We can create a class conform to this protocol

```
class SimpleClass: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String = "A very simple class."
    var anotherProperty: Int = 69105
    func adjust() {
        simpleDescription += "  Now 100% adjusted."
    }
}
```

We can get and set the value of property simpleDescription easily.

```
let a = SimpleClass()
a.simpleDescription = "new description"
print(a.simpleDescription)
```

What does `get` do in `var simpleDescription: String { get }`? Can we remove it?

Comment: Please read [Protocols: Property Requirements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID269) in the Swift Language Guide. If you try to remove it you get a meaningful error message.

Comment: No. You need to specify `get` and/or `set`. At least one requirement is required. It means you need to implement a getter but the setter is not necessary.

Comment: I see. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Brief Background on Protocols**

Any class, structure, or enumeration that implements all of the code defined within a protocol is said to conform to that protocol. A protocol can require any conforming type to provide a property (an instance property or type property with a particular name and type).<sup>1</sup> Each property defined in a protocol (such as `var simpleDescription: String` in the below example) must also specify after the type declaration (like type `String` in the below example) whether it is gettable `{ get }` or gettable and settable `{ get set }`.

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}
```

**Gettable { get } vs. Gettable and Settable Properties { get set }**

In general, properties that are gettable and settable `{ get set }` **MUST** be settable, meaning that the property's value **CAN** be edited/mutated. As such, properties that are gettable and settable **CANNOT** be a constant stored property (properties initialized with the `let` keyword) or a read-only computed property. If the protocol only requires a property to be gettable `{ get }`, the requirement can be satisfied by any kind of property, and it’s valid for the property to be also settable if this is useful for your own code.<sup>1</sup>

Examples of gettable properties vs gettable and settable properties:

```
// Gettable (var property)

protocol FishSpecies {
    var speciesName: String { get }
}

struct Fish: FishSpecies {
    var height: Int
    var weight: Int
    var speciesName: String
}

var tuna = FishSpecies(speciesName: “Yellowfin”)
print(tuna.speciesName) // returns “Yellowfin”
tuna.speciesName = “Thunnus albacares”
print(tuna.speciesName) // returns “Thunnus albacares”
```

```
// Gettable (let 'constant' property)

protocol FishSpecies {
    var speciesName: String { get }
}

struct Fish: FishSpecies {
    var height: Int
    var weight: Int
    let speciesName: String
}

let tuna = FishSpecies(fishName: “Yellowfin”)
print(tuna.speciesName) // returns “Yellowfin”
```

```
// Gettable and Settable (Constant Property)

protocol FullyNamed {
    var fullName: String { get set }
}

struct Golfer: FullyNamed {
    let fullName: String
}

let baller = Golfer(fullName: “Collin Morikawa”)
// -> Error message: Type ‘Golfer’ does not conform to protocol ‘FullyNamed’
// Gettable and Settable properties cannot be constant stored properties
```

```
// Gettable and Settable (Computed Property)

protocol FullyNamed {
    var fullName: String { get }
}

struct Golfer: FullyNamed {
    fileprivate var name: String
    var fullName: String {
        get {
            return name
        }
        set {
            name = newValue
        }
    }
}

var bigCat = Golfer(name: "Woods")
print(bigCat.fullName) // returns "Woods"
bigCat.fullName = "Tiger Woods"
print(bigCat.fullName) // returns "Tiger Woods"
```

**References/Further Reading**

1. Apple's Swift Documentation on [Protocols: Property Requirements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID269)
2. Apple's Swift Documentation on [Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)